# Adding Metadata in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

Is there a way to add metadata to properties while importing the documents into the MarkLogic database? If yes, please suggest the procedure to do it.
Also could you please let me know how do we add metadata to images.

Comment: You received assistance on your original inquiry and then assistance on two additional questions you asked in comments rather than as new posts. This thread is still open. If one of the answers provided you with the solution, please accept the answer. Otherwise, please revise your question so that others can help. Accepting answers keeps Stack Overflow clean ans useful.

Answer (score 3):

In Current versions of MarkLogic, the solution is to use document properties:  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/properties#id_19516

This is actually a second fragment(think 'document' for simplicity) on the same URI and **can be updated/inserted in the same transaction as the document insert/update**. In fact, since properties are actually a separate fragment all-together, it is even possible to insert properties(blind properties) on a URI that does not even have an associated document!

Please note: This does create an additional fragment per document. Therefore, if you have the ability to use an envelope pattern on your non-binary content and reserve the need for document properties only for binary content, then this is likely the most efficient solution.

Comment: Thanks David. Also while we use the xdmp:document-filter we fetch the metadata. If its an image, how can we add additional meta data such as Title or description to the image?

Comment: HI. You should really open new items for new questions -related or not. It keeps Stack Overflow more clean and useful.  As for your first item - as stated before, properties are just another fragment. You can write the entire XML yourself or add additional properties(XML Fragments) as you wish using xdmp:document-add-property, for instance.... As for your second question, it also depends on how you plan on seaching.. cts, search library, via java or json.. But in all cases, you specify that you want to search both the document and properties fragments via options.